# Need to acces a folder in a server with desktop java application

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I have developed a face recognition application using javaCV and like to put my MySQL DB and Training image set in a to server accomplish a centralized online data set that i can access anywhere  , Can anyone suggest me a method to get training images folder for processing in desktop java application

below is the method i pass images for recognition

```
public int FRecognizer(String path) {

    String trainingDir = "C:\\Users\\Kavinda\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Eagle_EYE\\trainingImages";


    Mat testImage = imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    File root = new File(trainingDir);

    FilenameFilter imgFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            name = name.toLowerCase();
            return name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".pgm") || name.endsWith(".png");
        }
    };
```